JUnit test failing Status expected:<201> but was:<404> (SOLVED)
I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out this issue, but when I'm running my tests on my UserControllerTest class I'm getting Status expected:<201> but was:<404>.
Here's my UserController class:
package com.kiingdom.streamingsite.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.kiingdom.streamingsite.model.User;
import com.kiingdom.streamingsite.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {
    
    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

        @PostMapping
        public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
            User createdUser = userService.saveUser(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }

        @GetMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
            Optional<User> user = userService.getUserById(id);
            return user.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        }

        @GetMapping("/username/{username}")
        public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
            Optional<User> user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
            return user.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        }

        @GetMapping("/email/{email}")
        public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
            Optional<User> user = userService.getUserByEmail(email);
            return user.map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        }

        @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUsers() {
            List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
            userService.deleteUser(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
}

and here's my UserControllerTest:
package com.kiingdom.streamingsite.controller;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.kiingdom.streamingsite.model.User;
import com.kiingdom.streamingsite.service.UserService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@Import(UserControllerTest.TestSecurityConfig.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    private User testUser;
    private Gson gson;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        gson = new Gson();

        testUser = new User();
        testUser.setId(123L);
        testUser.setUsername("testuser123");
        testUser.setEmail("testuser123@test.com");
        testUser.setPassword("testpassword123");
        testUser.setFirstName("Test");
        testUser.setLastName("User");
    }

    @Test
    void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting test for createUser");

        when(userService.saveUser(any(User.class))).thenReturn(testUser);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/users")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(gson.toJson(testUser)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username").value("testuser123"))
            .andDo(result -> System.out.println("Response content: " + result.getResponse().getContentAsString()));

        System.out.println("Completed test for createUser");
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    static class TestSecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                            .anyRequest().permitAll());
            return http.build();
        }
    }
}

It seems like the api isnt getting recognised but I have no idea why
I've triple checked the api endpoints and I really hope this isnt just me making a silly mistake and wasting people's time but I've seriously tried.

I didn't exactly fix the issue but I just stopped using MockMvc and just used HttpStatus to test them and it worked, so it must have been an issue with MockMvc
